# Using bluetooth in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mobile, cordova, bluetooth

I've been trying to develope some mobile app and I'm thinking of picking up AngularJS+ZeptoJS.

But there is one problem - I couldn't find anything about accessing the bluetooth actions with Angular. I've looked through some tutorials but haven't find a single word about it. I've been thinking if it is even possible?

I mean - accessing bluetooth in mobile-app ( created in angularjs, converted in phonegap ). Not mobile-web.

I'm quite new with mobile app programming so please don't hurt me :)

And also a little bit desperate to get the answer..

Comment: Can you even access bluetooth from a web browser? I don't think you can unless there's an API for it on your device

Comment: I meant from mobile app, so my application converted in PhoneGap to..let's call it native.

Comment: You should probably mention that in your question.

Comment: This is not an AngularJS question (or iOS or Android, for that matter).  It is a Cordova question.  I've edited your tags.  Hopefully the Cordova community can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a PhoneGap plugin for accessing Bluetooth:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/23

Once you get the plugin installed, you can access it via Angular.  I recommend creating a service for interacting with it.  It will go a little something like this:

```
App.factory('bluetooth', function() {
    var bluetoothSerial = cordova.require('bluetoothSerial');

    return {
        sendMessage: function(message) {
            // interact with bluetoothSerial
        }
    };
});
```

Then, your controllers can require it:

```
App.controller('appCtrl', function(bluetooth) {
    $scope.communicate = function() {
        bluetooth.sendMessage("all your base are belong to us");
    };
});
```

Good luck!